# Integration over a finite-dimensional subspace of Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration, hilbert-spaces, gaussian

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with inner product $\langle,\rangle$, let $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$, and let $A: H\to H$ be a symmetric, positive definite and invertible operator.
Let $u\in H$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, I aim to evaluate  the following integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left\langle A \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k-A^{-1}u\right), \sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k -A^{-1}u\right\rangle \right)\, dx_1\ldots dx_n.
$$
It would be ideal if it can be computed for general $u$, but
I am happy to assume $u$ lies in the subspace $H_n$ spanned by $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$.

---

My attempt:

To evaluate the integral, I try to rewrite the integral as an integral of Gaussian density. Note that
\begin{align*}
&\left\langle A \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k-A^{-1}u\right), \sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k -A^{-1}u\right\rangle 
\\
&=\left\langle   \sum_{k=1}^n x_k A e_k- u, \sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k -A^{-1}u\right\rangle 
\\
&=x^\top \mathbf{A} x- 2x^\top \mathbf{b} +\langle u, A^{-1} u\rangle,
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{A}=(A_{ij})_{i,j}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\mathbf{b}=(b_i)_{i=1}^n\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are defined as
$$
A_{ij} = \langle  Ae_i, e_j\rangle, \quad b_i = \langle  u, e_i\rangle.
$$
As $\mathbf{A}$ is a positive definite matrix, it is invertible. Then
\begin{align*}
x^\top \mathbf{A} x- 2x^\top \mathbf{b} +\langle u, A^{-1} u\rangle
= (x-\mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{b})^\top \mathbf{A} (x-\mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{b})
-  \mathbf{b}^\top  \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{b}+ \langle u, A^{-1} u\rangle. 
\end{align*}
If I could show
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
&\mathbf{b}^\top  \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{b}- \langle u, A^{-1} u\rangle
=0,
\end{align}
then I can rewrite the integral as an integration with a [multivariate Gaussian density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), which can be computed involving the determinant of  $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$. However, I am not sure whether (1) holds or not.
Even assuming $u=\sum_{k=1}^n \langle u,e_k\rangle  e_k$, we still need to show
$$
\sum_{k,l=1}^m \langle  u, e_k\rangle \left(( \mathbf{A}^{-1})_{kl}
-\langle A^{-1}e_k ,e_l\rangle
\right) \langle  u, e_l\rangle=0.
$$
It is unclear to me whether the identity holds, since typically  $A$ may not map $H_n$ into $H_n$.

This seems to be related to the matrix representation of an inverse operator, which has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366762/matrix-of-an-invertible-operator-is-also-invertible-proof). However, it assumes $A$ maps $H_n$ into itself, and hence we can use the same basis for the range of $A$.